# How to create one-to-one mapping in EF from two tables to one source?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I want to have 2 models, for Example, "Person" and "Animal". both are modeled in the DB (postrge) with `image_binary_id` column.

```csharp
    public class Person
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ImageBinary ImageBinary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ImageBinary ImageBinary { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I want the image data table will "provide" images for both objects, using the model:

```csharo
    public class ImageBinary
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

In the DB, I have foreign keys connected "person.image_binary_id => image_binary.id"

How can I define the mapping in the code so the insert will be proper, in 1 transaction, like this:

```csharp
var image = new ImageBinary(...);
var person = new Person() 
{
    ...,
    ImageBinary = image
}
PersonRepository.AddPerson(person);
```

I tried mapping the `person` it like this, but that causes the image_binary_id be `null` on insert:

```csharp
entity.HasOne(x => x.ImageBinary)
   .WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey("ImageBinary", "Id");
```

I understand that if "ImageBinary" table will hold `person` \ `animal` columns, this might solve it since it will have "navigation" back (adding parameter to `WithOne()`)- but i dont want to add more columns (unless I have to...).

I thought about adding junction tables (person_id, image_binary_id) but that seems bad maintainability since I would have to add one for all future models as well.

Using .NET 5 with EF Core Version 5.

Any thoughts and solutions are welcome.

Comment: *unless I have to* -- You better do. I've always found that to be the best solution to such *polymorphic associations*. Or even create an image table per entity. It's really not as bad as it may sound.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, you suggest to add columns to the `ImageBinary` table, with the type of the referred object ? for this case the extra column will be `entity_type`  with the value options `person \ animal` - so a query from this table will be based on the Id + type ?

Comment: No, I'd add a _foreign key_ per entity, so you have data integrity.

Answer (score -1):

This is the the code first implementation of what you are trying to do.

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public long ImageBinRef { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ImageBinRef")]
        //or [ForeignKey(nameof(ImageBinRef))] I like this version better
        public ImageBinary ImageBinary { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is some explanation of what I have done here

- Key attribute tells Ef that Id is primary key
- DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) tells ef that it's
  auto incremented
- **The ForeignKey attribute adds fk constraint and index to ImageBinRef** property I have defined for you in my answer so the example you are trying to run will work now

one other important thing here is that your ImageBinary class' primary key is long type which is not nullable and does not accept null as a value.
This is important because now when you delete a person record it will also delete the ImageBinary record connected to that (I do not know if this is what you want)  if you dont want that record to be deleted simply declare the property like this

```
public long? ImageBinRef { get; set; } //Notice the question mark
```

the question mark means that it's a nullable type, so now when you delete the person record it **will not delete** the referenced image record..

note that strings are by default nullable therefore you do not need to worry about this:

say you have COUNTRIES table and PERSON table

```
public class PERSON{
   
 [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int PersonRowid {get;set:}
 public string PersonName {get;set:}

 public string PersonCountryCode {get;set;}

 [ForeignKey("PersonCountryCode")]
 public COUNTRIES Country {get;set;}
}

public class COUNTRIES{
   
 [Key]
 public string CountryCode {get;set:}
 public string CountryName {get;set:}
}
```

in this example when you delete a person the country record will still remain in the table, however if you change the property type of countrycode from string to int when you delete a person record it will also remove that country from the DB which probably is not something you want, to prevent these kind of scenarios we define our properties as nullable..

excuse if I made any typo, I have not used a compiler while adding the code samples.

EDIT:

```
public class Animal
    {
        [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public long ImageBinRef { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ImageBinRef")]
        public ImageBinary ImageBinary { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You missed the essence of the question. Where's the `Animal` class? It's about two classes pointing to one reference. Required or not is all beside the point.

Comment: @GertArnold I've edited the answer accordingly.. It does not matter I showed him how to do pointing.. he could easly do this too

Comment: Yeah and now you have something you clearly didn't test. This really isn't something you just type away without even compiling, let alone testing.